# Is there a formula way to check if a cell is a merged cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I find that merged cells makes it harder to build formulas.

For example, in the following worksheet, Cells C7 and D7 are merged. As a consequence, `C7` returns `Merged Cell of C7 and D7`, and `=D7` returns `0`. F5 Contains a formula `=C5:C9`, but I'm looking for a formula to ignore merged cells and return I5:I9.

Does anyone know if there is a formula way (rather than VBA way) to check if a cell is a merged cell (or if an area contains a merged cell)?

[image]

Comment: No, a formula cannot determine the format of a cell including if it is merged.  Merged cells keep the value in the upper left corner cell of the merged area.  All other cells are blank.

Comment: Would be pretty easy in VBA though...